# UIScrollView strange ScrollIndicator as compare to UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using a UIScrollView and while scrolling it I noticed the ScrollIndicator was shrinking based on my scroll inset. But this is not the case with UITableView.

I have tried doing `[scrView setBounces:NO]`, but that doesn't make it more user-friendly and also it hinders the scroll movement.

Is there any way to make **UIScrollView scrollIndicator same as UITableView scrollIndicator**?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you mean? I am not fully following what you mean.

Comment: @Paul Peelen Yes,But does not post screen shot need 12 rep.so,post Screen Shot link..!

Comment: @PaulPeelen what i mean is create a UIScrollView and try to scroll it to the bottom, the more u scroll the more the indicator shrinks, i want to remove this shrink effect. it will be clear when u try creating a scrollview and see the behaviour after scrolling it and pulling the scroll at the bottom.

Comment: ok, the same effect exist in a UITableViewController, and is standard in cocoa-touch. It's the bounce effect that pull the table/view back in place. You can check the Mail.app app on your iPhone/ipad and scroll to the bottom, you'll see the same thing there.

Comment: What I mean is, its default in UIKit. Try switching off bouncing effect, but I don't think it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a UITableViewController you can switch Bounces off, which means that tableView can not be elastically pulled upwards and then it bounces back. This also means that the scrollbar will not shrink.

You can switch it off using `setBounces`:

```
[self.tableView setBounces:NO];
```

You can do the same in a UIScrollView. See documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/bounces

Comment: thanks, pls read my question i already tried setBounces but that hinders the free movement for scroll view, is there any other solution for the same. I mean with setBounces:NO user can;t scroll beyond the contentSize which is not what i want, it makes scrollview too stagnant looking, Any other solution u have?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. This is, as I wrote in my comment above, default in UIKit.